# Best practice to propagate theme through flutter screens

Tags: flutter

I've made a basic theme for my app and set it in the MaterialApp widget

```
 ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.black,
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
  buttonColor: Colors.purple,

);
```

but it seems the theme is not being updated on MaterialAppshome

```
home: LoginScreen()
```

. the button nor the background (supposed to be black and gray) aint updating...

[image]

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#using-a-theme):

> ## Using a Theme

> Now that you’ve defined a theme, use it within the widgets’ build() methods by using the Theme.of(context) method.

> The Theme.of(context) method looks up the widget tree and returns the nearest Theme in the tree. If you have a standalone Theme defined above your widget, that’s returned. If not, the app’s theme is returned.

> In fact, the FloatingActionButton uses this technique to find the accentColor.

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  child: Text(
    'Text with a background color',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
  ),
),
```